# merging a sort array and unsorted array

Tags: algorithm, sorting

Merge a sorted array with unsorted array to give a final sorted array. Can it be better done, the not obvious way.

```
final_sorted_array=merge(sort(unsorted_array), sorted_array)
```

I am assuming *merge* step similar to found in *merge sort*

and we know any best is limited by O(n log n) in general. I am trying to understand how a ordered data (knowing the information about data) can be useful to what extent in general.

Comment: Since you're looking for a general idea, my approach would be to use a linked list instead of an array for the sorted data structure. This would allow you to loop through the unsorted array in linear time to the number of elements in this unsorted array, and for each element use binary search to find the position it should be put in, in the sorted datastructure, in log N time. The insert of any element would be constant for a Linked List, resulting in a running time of `O(m log (m+n))`, where m is the number of unsorted elements and n the number of pre-sorted elements.

Comment: @Exfridos - how would you do a binary search on a linked list? The obvious way should be the fastest, and consider the case of a top down merge sort, the left half is sorted first, resulting in left half sorted, right half unsorted, similar to the problem statement. Then the right half is sorted and the two halves are merged.

Comment: It's not obvious what the 'obvious way' means, e.g. "concat the two lists and sort them" is easier to code and could be argued to be an obvious (easy) way.  *Did the question specify what the obvious way was?* and *is this homework?*

Comment: @rcgldr Touché. Can't do binary search in log N on a Linked List. I must admit ignorance with the given amount of information and say that I cannot find a way faster than your given solution. You're already cleverly using merge-sort to abuse the fact that the right side is sorted. Thus, your final running time is O(n log n) to sort the unsorted array, followed by the merge step, which takes O(n+m). There is no (known) faster way to sort arbitrary data and the merge step is linear in the total number of elements, which is much better than if you concatenated the two and used eg. Quicksort.

Comment: you may use a concept of insertion sort. starting from the first element of unsorted array, you insert it into sorted array from the right end until it reaches its proper position. although the worst case runtime is `O(n*m), n=size of sorted, m=size of unsorted`, it could take only `O(m)` in best case

Answer (score 0):

Suppose your first array is called A1 of `n1` elements and your second one is called A2 of `n2` elements:

extend the length of A1 and append A2 to it at the cost of `O(n2 + c)`, where `c` is a constant. Apply quick sort and get it ordered at another cost of `O( (n1+n2)*log(n1+n2) )`. You mentioned you didn't want the obvious way, however, you wanted to get the job done the best way. This is likely the best way, because it allows you to still use regular arrays which are usually the fastest data structures to work in general (of course it depends specifically on which task you are working on).

However, a different possibility, is to make A1 a linked list insetad of a regular array, for the purpose of this analysis we will not consider the costs of transforming A1 from an regular array into a linked list. Therefore, the approach would be to insert ordered each element of A2 into A1. The obvious way to insert ordered would be to verify each element of A1 and then decide where to insert, at the cost of `O(n1 + c)` for each insertion. However, a smarter method would be to make a binary search over A1 to decide where each element of A2 should be inserted in, at the cost of `O(log(n1) + c)` for each insertion. In this case, there would be `n2` insertions, being the total cost `n2*O(log(n1) + c)`. In this approach you wouldn't need to move any of A1 elements, since we are assuming you use a linked list, all you need is to check these elements. That's why this asymptotic function looks better, this data structure gives you the power to only look at A1 original elements without actually moving them.

To decide which approach you should use, I recommend that you analyse the algorithm which comes after the arrays merge, choosing the option that best fits your needs.